# Know the name of the form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a button called "Next" that exists in a couple of asp.net pages. Actually it is in a User Control. When "Next" is clicked it calls a function `CheckServicesAndStates` in JavaScript. I want to know the page that has initiated this "Next" button click.

Can anyone tell me how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href
```

contains the current url.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to the form then check for the existence of it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sender" value="page-name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In a `<button>` event handler `this.form.name` is the name of the containing form.

```
<form name=foo>
  <button type=button onclick="alert(this.form.name)">
</form>
```

alerts "foo" when clicked.